# How to read hidden tab of excel workbook in python?

Tags: python, pandas

There are 3 different tabs in the workbook I am trying to read via python workbook.xlsm: x, y, z (z is hidden in excel).

```
import pandas as pd

file=f'S:\filelocation\...\workbook.xlsm'
ws=pd.ExcelFile(file)
ds=pd.read_excel(ws,'z',index=0).fillna(0)
```

this code returns "ValueError: 'z' is not in list" as z is a hidden tab. "XLRDError: No sheet named <'z'>"

How do I go around this problem?

Comment: I think you can usually see hidden sheets from excel using code. Are you sure that it is called `sheet 3` and not `Sheet 3` or `Sheet3` ?

Comment: yes. above is using hypothetical name as an example

Comment: amend sheet names to avoid confusions

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As an aside, why are you using `ExcelFile` here?

Answer (score 1):

By default pandas will read all sheets. 
Probably it may be '`Sheet 3`'instead of `'sheet 3'` (s caps)

```
import pandas as pd

xls = pd.ExcelFile('excel.xlsx')

sheets = xls.book.sheets()
print(sheets)
```

Then check the visibility of each sheet
    for sheet in sheets:
        print(sheet.name, sheet.visibility)

Hope this helps.